# Mojo BudgetService

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, webkit

### I start my Meteor App with "meteor run android". I get some Errors:

I20171121-07:41:24.201(1)? 11-21 01:41:00.483  4067  4172 E chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(289)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
I20171121-07:41:24.207(1)? 11-21 01:41:00.917  4067  4127 E chromium: [ERROR:service_manager.cc(156)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface:
blink::mojom::BudgetService exposed by: content_browser

-

I20171121-07:41:24.208(1)? 11-21 01:41:01.255  4097  4131 E chromium: [ERROR:BudgetService.cpp(167)] Unable to connect to the Mojo BudgetService.
I20171121-07:41:57.587(1)? 11-21 01:41:40.944  4067  4067 I MeteorWebApp: Serving asset bundle with version: 5c0acfb7c964b67f3c1ec29335c3fb0e27b7d59d
I20171121-07:41:57.878(1)? 11-21 01:41:41.234  4067  4127 E chromium: [ERROR:service_manager.cc(156)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface:
blink::mojom::BudgetService exposed by: content_browser

Has anybody an idea how to solve these problems??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Having a similar problem.  Have not found a solution.  Others seem to be stuck on this as well.